# How to find difference between two dates in seconds in different timezones

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, timezone

I have a piece of code which finds the difference between two dates(in the format of yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) . This code is run in multiple servers across the globe. One of the two dates is the current time in that particular timezone where the code is being run(server time) and another is the time obtained from a database. if the difference between these two times is greater than 86400 seconds(1day), then it should print "invalid" else, it should print "valid".
Problem im facing with the code is when I run it on my local, its working fine, but when i deploy it onto a server in US, its taking GMT time into consideration and not local time. 
Wherever the code is run, I want the difference between current time and time fetched from the database, and if its greater than 86400 seconds, i want to print invalid. How to achieve this in java? 
PS: I tried with Date object, but its considering GMT only everywhere.

Comment: Would setting the default TimeZone work for you?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)

Comment: No, setting a default time zone will work only if a code is deployed in a single timezone. My code will be deployed in multiple servers across the globe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use GMT everywhere and only convert to the local times for display purposes.

To find the difference, convert both times to the same timezone (say GMT) and take the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by the below example code.

```
Date date = new Date();

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

Date date1 = dateformat.parse(formatter.format(date));

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

Date date2 = dateformat.parse(formatter.format(date)); 
// Prints the date in the IST timezone
//    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

**Now compare date1 with date2**

Answer (score 0):

First, I concur with Peter Lawrey's answer up there. It is usually good practice to store all time in the database for a single zone, and render it with offset for the user based upon the user's locale.

To find the difference, use the method `getTime()` to get the time in milliseconds from the epoch for each date. The calculation for the difference of 1 day is then 86400 * 1000 milliseconds. Or, perhaps, store the time in milliseconds from epoch in the database, and use a DB procedure/function at the time of retrieval.

Hope this helps.